# What injection $2^\omega\to \omega_1$ can we take?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading about the continuum hypothesis. As I understand it, in general, we have $2^\omega\ge \omega_1$. So we could build for example a model of $ZFC$ where we have $2^\omega=\omega_2$. But Just using $ZFC$, (or maybe just $ZF$?), what would be the injection $2^\omega\to \omega_1$ be? If there is already an answer that I missed you can redirect me so I will check it.

Comment: Do you mean *surjection*? There is no injection $2^\omega\rightarrow\omega_1$ unless $\mathsf{CH}$ holds, so we certainly can't construct one in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. (Also, you shouldn't use the word "the" here - if there is one map of any of the relevant types, there will be many - but that's a minor issue.)

Comment: A think the existence of the injection $\omega_1 \to 2^\omega$ comes from Axiom of Choice.  By choice, $2^\omega$ has the same cardinality as some ordinal, and that ordinal has to be bigger than or equal to $\omega_1$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I actually meant injection $\omega_1\to 2^{\omega}$. Sorry about that, I was very tired

Answer (score 3):

I think you're mixing things up a bit (see my comment to the OP), so I'm going to describe the situation with respect to a couple different kinds of map we might look for.

Within $\mathsf{ZFC}$, $2^\omega$ is in bijection with some ordinal $\alpha\ge\omega_1$. Consequently we are guaranteed the existence of an injection $\omega_1\rightarrow 2^\omega$. However, there is no reason to expect that there is a "natural" such injection. For example that it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is no such injection, so building one really does require choice; more subtly, large cardinal axioms rule out "simply-definable" such maps in a precise way (e.g. assuming infinitely many Woodin cardinals there is no projectively definable injection $\omega_1\rightarrow 2^\omega$).

Two more types of map are basically equivalent to $\mathsf{CH}$ (so we won't find $\mathsf{ZFC}$-provable examples). Specifically, $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that any set which injects into a well-orderable set, or admits a surjection from a well-orderable set, is itself well-orderable (this is a good exercise). So it's easy to show in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that the following are equivalent:

- $\mathsf{CH}$ ("There is a bijection between $\omega_1$ and $2^\omega$");
- There is an injection $2^\omega\rightarrow\omega_1$; and
- There is a surjection $\omega_1\rightarrow 2^\omega$.

Consequently, you can't hope for $\mathsf{ZFC}$-examples of the latter two kinds of map.

Finally, there is a positive result: within $\mathsf{ZF}$, we do get a simple surjection $2^\omega\rightarrow\omega_1$. Specifically, identify $2^\omega$ with the set of binary relations on $\omega$. Now consider the map $\mu$ sending a binary relation $R$ on $\omega$ to $0$ if $R$ is not a well-ordering of some subset of $\omega$ and to the ordinal which is the ordertype of $R$ otherwise. This map is clearly a surjection from $2^\omega$ to $\omega_1$: by definition, $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal, so the ordinals $<\omega_1$ are exactly the ordertypes of well-orderings of subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Just when we write $2^{\omega}$ we mean the cardinal exponentiation right? Because if it was the ordinal exponentiation, then $2^{\omega}:=\bigcup\limits_{n<\omega}2^n=\omega$, right? This is always confusing to me. Actually it would be more clear if we would write $2^{\aleph_0}$ no?